# ASCII to raster conversion

Tags: r, raster

I am using following code for opening a Raster image in single band (with temperature values)-

```
library(raster)
nrows = 764
ncols = 1022
df1 <- read.table("AA092800_1.asc", skip = 11, header = FALSE, sep = "\t", dec = ",")
r.mat <- matrix(data = "df1", nrow = nrows, ncol = ncols)
r <- raster(r.mat)
extent(r) <- extent(c(30,45.95,30,45.95))
res(r)

plot(r)
```

I am doing a silly mistake and the code is throwing the error-

"Error in setValues(r, as.vector(t(x))) : 
  values must be numeric, integer, logical or factor"

The input Ascii file is attached.[input Ascii file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ck19W85MFURnUtMXItaFJZRFU/view?usp=sharing).

Please help.

Comment: You just need `r.mat <- as.matrx(df1)` as the 5th line. Are you aware of what your line actually produces?

Comment: Thanks Nicola, Yes I was not aware what my line is producing. Now i got my mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: You could post and accept that as your answer. Or else please delete this.