# Batch process multiple ASCII to Raster files in R

Tags: r, ascii, raster, tiff, terra

I am trying to convert some `ASCII` test files into `.tif` files, so i can use the `.tif` files in `bnspatial`.

Any suggestions? Is there a package out there that does this or do i need to link R with a GIS software?

Comment: `raster()` function in `raster` package looks like it should do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087320/ascii-to-raster-conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something along these lines:

```
library(terra)
fasc <- list.files(pattern='\\.asc$', full=TRUE)
ftif <- gsub("\\.asc$", ".tif", fasc)

for (i in 1:length(fasc)) {
    r <- rast(fasc[i])
    r <- writeRaster(r, ftif[i])
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert. Can you also provide a `terra` equivalent answer? Thank you!

Comment: I updated it. Now using `terra`